# converting element to an array in jsonb postgres

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert an element which is a element in jsonb to array. before it was student could have only one contact, now they can have multiple contacts.

current

```
{
   "studentId":"123",
   "contact":{
      "name":"parent1",
      "address":"address1"
   }
}
```

now we will have

```
{
   "studentId":"123",
   "guardian":[
      {
         "name":"parent1",
         "address":"address1"
      },
      {
         "name":"parent2",
         "address":"address2"
      }
   ]
}
```

how do I convert the contact object to guardian? Thanks

Comment: `data['guardian'] = jsonb_build_array(data->'contact')`?

Comment: Where does the second address come from?

Comment: Please show us your table schema, and format the sample data as actual JSON

Comment: second on can be added in further... so currently converting the existing one to array as first element

Comment: @bergi- can this be used to update sql the existing data? data['guardian'] = jsonb_build_array(data->'contact')

Comment: Are you really still using postgres 9.1? It doesn't actually support JSONB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UPDATE` use [`delete (-) and concatenate (||) operators`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) :

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col = col - 'contact' 
          || jsonb_build_object('guardian', jsonb_build_array(col->'contact'));
```

To simultaneously update and add an element :

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col = col - 'contact' 
          || jsonb_build_object('guardian', jsonb_build_array(col->'contact', '{"name":"parent2", "address":"address2"}'));
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-9ktjJF6)

Comment: Thanks so much... it worked. Appreciate your help. next time, will start do the dbfiddle.